# Knockout Custom binding handler for updating parent element attr value to child element

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have an scenario like below,

```
<div data-val='Hello World'>
<p data-bind=''>"Hello World" should get append here</p>
</div>
```

I want append parent div's data-val attribute value to paragraph, using custom binding handler so whenever data-val value get updated then paragraph content also should get updated with that new value,

it is possible with KO, since am new to knockout.

any help much appreciate and sorry if am trying to achieve anything wrong for KO structure.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what you're trying to achieve? What's modifying `data-val`? Can we get that data into Knockout in a different way? Which browsers must be supported?

Comment: I will modify the data-val using JQuery, and we can't get that data into knockout.

Comment: What stops you from writing it to an observable through `ko.dataFor` / `ko.contextFor`?

Comment: You are trying to create an observable manually, which defeats the purpose of Knockout.